# How to get full path of a given path

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a variable define as:

```
set filePath=".\file.txt"
```

I'm writing a windows batch file. Need to convert the path stored in variable 'filePath' to its fullpath (physical path).

How can I get the full path of this path? Please help!

Comment: using coding or just to learn where it is?

Comment: I'm writing a windows batch file. Need to convert the path stored in variable 'filePath' to its fullpath (physical path).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your question is tagged "command-line" I assume you want to do this in a Windows bat script. There you can expand a variable to the full path using the following syntax:

```
%~fI
```

where I is the name of the variable.

The following script will print you the full path to ".\file.txt":

```
set filePath=".\file.txt"
for %%F in (%filePath%) do set filePath=%%~fF
echo %filePath%
```

A full reference of available substitutions is contained in the description of the **[`for`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)** command (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx).